# jQuery rule for removing all elements, if any of its child element at any depth has a specific class

Tags: jquery

What's the simplest rule which takes this DOM:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>  
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="remove">link</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>  
            <div>
                <span class="ok"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>  
            <div class="remove"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and removes all `<li>` elements, if any of them has a child at any depth which contains `"remove"` class. The result html is shown below:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>  
            <div>
                <span class="ok"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li:has(.remove)').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

From the docs:

> The expression $('div:has(p)') matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists
>   anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNcKE/1/